# How to use Controller function in JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a this JavaScript function:

```
function notificationDivPressed(element,userId,numberOfUsers) {
   $.ajax({
      url: '/Notification/ChangeReadStatus',
      type: "POST", cache: false,
      data: { arg: userId },
      success: function (data) {
         //some code
      }
    });
```

and this is ChangeReadStatus() function from Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void ChangeReadStatus(string id)
{
   //some code
}
```

why 'id' value in ChangeReadStatus is equal to 'null'?

Comment: `datatype: json`  needed

Comment: @Ani: Wrong; MVC is perfectly capable of handling form posts.

Comment: just change your data to: "data : { "id" : userId }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your HTTP requests passes `arg`, not `id`.

If you want to pass a parameter, you need to pass it with the same name.